# Select Mesh from scene which has volume equal or close to the active mesh

Tags: mesh, scripting, select

I am trying to develop a code which can Calculate volume of active mesh object and find another mesh and select it from scene which has volume equal to active mesh or (smaller or greater than active mesh, lets say the difference could be 10% in volume of both).

For eg. My active mesh is "Monkey_susan" it has volume 10cubic centimeters.
and lets say in scene there is a object named "Susan" which has volume about 9cubic centimeters. which is in range of 90% of "Monkey_susan" volume, so difference in volume is 10% so it is matched and then selected.

Comment: Not sure it completely answers your question but here's how to calculate volume of an object : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/99676/86891

Comment: I think it does 60percent of my work., so yeah the rest is just to compare objects, thanks mate